# How can I customize the child items in a TreeView of QML?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

QML:

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.5
import QtQml.Models 2.2
import filesystem_browser 1.0

ApplicationWindow
{
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    ItemSelectionModel
    {
        id: sel
        // This model is comming from C++' class DisplayFileSystemModel.
        model: treeViewModel
    }

    TreeView {
        id: view
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins: 2 * 12
        model: treeViewModel
        rootIndex: root
        selection: sel

        TableViewColumn
        {
            title: "Name"
            role: "display"
            resizable: true
        }

        itemDelegate:
            Rectangle
            {
                id: dd
                color: "pink"
                height: 20

                Rectangle
                {
                    height: 20; width: 40; color: "green"; anchors.right: parent.right
                    border.width: 1
                }

                border.width: 1
                Text
                {
                    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                    text: styleData.value
                }
            }
    }
}
```

**C++**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    QStandardItemModel model;

    QStandardItem *item1 = new QStandardItem("File");
    item1->appendRows({new QStandardItem("New"),
                       new QStandardItem("Open"),
                       new QStandardItem("Open Recent"),
                       new QStandardItem("Close"),
                       new QStandardItem("Save..."),
                       new QStandardItem("Save As..."),
                       new QStandardItem("Import Audio File..."),
                       new QStandardItem("Print")
                      });

    QStandardItem *item3 = new QStandardItem("Edit");
    item3->appendRows({new QStandardItem("Undo"),
                       new QStandardItem("Redo"),
                       new QStandardItem("Cut"),
                       new QStandardItem("Copy"),
                       new QStandardItem("Paste"),
                       new QStandardItem("Delete"),
                       new QStandardItem("Select All")
                      });


    model.appendRow(item1);
    model.appendRow(item3);

    qmlRegisterUncreatableType<DisplayFileSystemModel>("filesystem_browser", 1, 0,
                                                       "FileSystemModel", "Cannot create");

    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("treeViewModel", &model);
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("root", model.indexFromItem(model.invisibleRootItem()));

    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:///main.qml")));

    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    return app.exec();
}
```

This results in:

[image]

I want to customize the child items and the parent item individually.
For example:

```
File //Parent item
    New.. // Child item
    Save.. // Child item
```

This current code puts the same customisation on the parent as well as the children.

Comment: In a TreeView, any element can be both a parent and a child at the same time. So your question isn't entirely clear. Maybe choosing a color based on the `row` or `column` number will help you?

Comment: @JarMan I tried this: `color: styleData.row ? "green":"yellow";` in the itemDelegate. This makes only 'File' item yellow and rest everything "green". I request you to show an example.

Comment: @Aquarius_Girl - Have you tried to appendRows to the child items. so each appliciable child entry, has their own appended row?  You might have to declare each QStandardItem variable in order to to do this.

Comment: @Aquarius_Girl - I don't have the appropriate environment to develop QT Code.  I have no interest in doing that work, if my very specific hint, isn't helpful (I know it will work but I have no desire to setup my development environment to test it out).

Comment: @SecurityHound Alright. I will find the relevant documention.

Comment: Something like: `QStandardItem *item1 = new QStandardItem("File");  QStandardItem *item2 = new QStandardItem("Save");  item1->appendRows({Item2},`  This should make Save a child of File.  [AppendRows](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandarditem.html#appendRow-1).  Don't understand the reason you declared item1 as a pointer, seems unnecessary, since it wasn't required for the [QStandardItemModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandarditemmodel.html) variable.

Comment: I am very thankful for your help. @SecurityHound I will try this tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My previous comment about using the `row` or `column` value was close, but incorrect. A quick look at the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-treeview.html#itemDelegate-prop) shows us that there is another property that gives us the `depth` of an item. So I think you can achieve what you want by simply doing something like this:

```
color: styleData.depth ? "blue" : "pink"
```